# can data in variables may leak? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, security

I'm working on referrals project and my test function looks like this (to check referred users):

```
$referrals = auth::user()->referrals;
echo $referrals;
```

The output of the following is like this:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"XYZ","email":"abc@def.com","is_subscribed":"0","is_referrer":"0","created_at":"Time here","referred_by":"1"}]
```

and in controller:

```
$referrals = auth::user()->referrals;
$host = request()->getHost();
$Link = $host.'?ref='.\Hashids::encode(auth()->user()->id);
foreach ($referrals as $users){
    return view('dashboard', compact('users', 'Link'));
}
```

All is working fine but I'm afraid in case my site get attacked it'll leak the email addresses of other referred users.

in my views I'm showing only "Name of referred users".

```
<td>
   {{ $users->name }}
</td>
```

is it okay? to do things like this?

thanks

Comment: No. The blade template is assembled server side. As long as you are not outputting the data to the view (and you are not running in dev mode on production), it would not be possible to leak.

Comment: Just a sidenote: you cant really call `return` on the first line of a `foreach` statement. Makes no sense.

Comment: thanks @Flame just realized it fixed

Comment: No problem. The most common case of data like this being leaked is due to misconfiguration of the production server. Ensure that your `APP_ENV` is set to production and turn off any error logging to the browser (its ok to keep error logging to files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The blade template is assembled server side. As long as you are not outputting the data to the view (and you are not running in dev mode on production), it would not be possible to leak. 
thank to!
– @Jeremy Harris

helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

The hacking of your site is not impossible but would be very difficult. 
The blade is very efficient in the separation between server side and client side. But you have to be careful about the custom functions created to models that used in blade could leak some information that you don´t want.

You can also declare the hidden values for models that are not shown in responses.

Hope it helped